# How to get all contracts with SendindBlue's API?

Tags: php, api, loops, foreach, each

I'm getting the contracts belongs to certain list with the code below. But they have 500 contacts per page limit and I have 5000. How can I loop with an offset?

```
$limit = 500; // int | Number of documents per page
$offset = 0; // int | Index of the first document of the page


try {
    $result = $apiInstance->getContactsFromList($listId, $modifiedSince, $limit, $offset);
    print_r($result);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Exception when calling ContactsApi->getContactsFromList: ', $e->getMessage(), PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Not sure where the 500 limit comes from, do you get an error with 5000?  If so, then you may have to just start with offset of 0, adding 500 until you get less than 500 contacts back (a simple loop should do it).

Comment: It's coming from their API, tried 5000 and said over the limit.

Comment: Yes :) It's Array.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need, basically it reads the data in chunks (specified by `$limit`) and each time it reads a full chunk, it adjusts the offset to read the next page...

```
$limit = 500; // int | Number of documents per page
$offset = 0; // int | Index of the first document of the page

try {
    do {
        $result = $apiInstance->getContactsFromList($listId, $modifiedSince, $limit, $offset);
        // How much data has been passed back, 
        $received = count($result);
        // Just to see each page being received
        echo $received.PHP_EOL;
        // Move offset on by entries in this page
        $offset += $received;
    }
    // Carry on while a full page has been retrieved
    while ($received == $limit);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Exception when calling ContactsApi->getContactsFromList: ', $e->getMessage(), PHP_EOL;
}
```

I'm assuming that

```
$received = count($result);
```

will work.

Comment: Huh got this error: Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in /Users/user/Sites/m/mail.php on line 22

Comment: Having a look at the data, try `$received = $result->count;`

Comment: Has this made any difference?